# Retrieving a column value from a row object: no encoder found

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I wrote the following code to take some action based on a field value for each row:

```
import spark.implicits._ 
table.map(line =>
          column_names.map(column =>
                      if (line.getAs[Int](column)==0)
                          println("yes")
                      )
          )
```

However I encounter the following error:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: No Encoder found for Unit
- array element class: "scala.runtime.BoxedUnit"
- root class: "scala.collection.immutable.List"
```

I understand that an encoder is required to convert objects and primitives in the Spark InternalRow, but the field that I'm trying to access contains an int, and based on my understanding the corresponding encoder should be available thanks to spark.implicits._.

Could you please tell me what am I missing and what should I do to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your map-statement returns `Unit` (i.e. nothing), for which there is no encoder. If you just want to print, then use `foreach` instead:

```
table.foreach(line =>
  column_names.foreach(column =>
    if (line.getAs[Int](column)==0)
      println("yes")
  )
)
```

otherwise, return something (ensure that you also return the same type in the `else`-clause, e.g.

```
table.map(line =>
  column_names.map(column =>
    if (line.getAs[Int](column)==0) {
      println("yes")
      "yes"
     } else {
       "no"
     }
  )
)
```